# Removing a CSS class from HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good Day,

I have the following image tag that is rendered:

```
<img id="map1" title="Positions" alt="Positions" height="348" width="556" src="http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/image_thumb_1263F129.png" class="ui-li-thumb">
```

I'm trying to remove the class:  ui-li-thumb.

This is what I have at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
    $("img#map1").removeClass("ul-li-thumb");
    $("img#map1").removeAttr("class");
</script>
```

Neither of them are working.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

TIA,

coson

Comment: Is the `<script>` above or below the `<img/>` in your HTML document?

Comment: What sort of errors do you get in the console?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo.

Comment: @TravisJ In that fiddle, your classes don't match up. That's why it's 'not working' :)

Comment: @TravisJ nevermind, I see its in the original now. Good catch

Comment: The script tag is at the bottom of the page after the <img/> tag in my document.

Comment: @Jesse, I don't see anything in the Firebug console output.

Comment: @coson please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're including jQuery in your code. Also, check for any errors in the browser console!

Another thing to do is to make sure the jQuery code runs *after* the document has loaded, something like:

```
$(function(){
    $("img#map1").toggleClass("ui-li-thumb", false);
});
```

***EDIT:***

Updated my answer based on Jesse's answer...yes, also make sure your class names are the same!

Answer (score 8):

Your HTML class is `ui-li-thumb`
And your jQuery class is `ul-li-thumb`;

Otherwise, make sure jQuery is loaded and try wrapping the script in a self firing function

Comment: i'm surprised there are any other comments than this lol.

Comment: I didn't catch it the first time around, either. Those damn 'i's and 'l's look almost identical at first glance...

Comment: Nice one...missed it too!

Comment: Wow, I missed that in his question, in your answer, and I stood there starting at it for a good 30 seconds before I got it! Good eyes!

Answer (score 0):

i think you should be using get.ElementByClass property